# mesa-common-dev: unmet dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, dependencies, opengl, mesa

I'm trying to install *mesa-common-dev* on Ubuntu LTS:

> sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev

however, the system returns:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
     mesa-common-dev : Depends: libgl-dev but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libglx-dev but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libglx-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

> apt-cache policy mesa-common-dev

```
mesa-common-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20.0.4-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     20.0.4-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

---

> apt-cache policy libgl-dev

```
libgl-dev:
  Installed: 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Candidate: 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.3.1-1 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

---

> apt-cache policy libglx-dev

```
libglx-dev:
  Installed: 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Candidate: 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.3.1-1 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

---

> apt-cache policy libdrm-dev

```
libdrm-dev:
  Installed: (nenhum)
  Candidate: 2.4.101-2
  Version table:
     2.4.101-2 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

---

Thank you so much

---

---

> grep -Rn --include=*.list ^[^#] /etc/apt/

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:5:deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:15:deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:24:deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:42:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:44:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:46:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4:deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:1:deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-beta.list:3:deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/ stable main
```

---

---

SUCCESS!!
I add:

> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted
> universe multiverse

in the *source.list* file.

thanks for helping me

Comment: Welcome. Please add the output of `grep -Rn --include=\*.list ^[^\#] /etc/apt/` to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`focal-updates` is missing in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, to correct the problem:

```
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted  universe multiverse" |\
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mesa-common-dev
```